# Performance impact of relationship queries in batch start

Tags: soql, batch, performance

For a new batch process I have a choice between immediately selecting relevant records in the `start` function (but using several [field]__r comparisons as they are junction objects being queried) or creating a new field on the records marking them for batch processing in an earlier stage and then perform an additional query in `execute` to 'manually' filter out the correct objects.

I remember reading that relationship fields and such all increase processing time, but is this impact big enough to warrant creating a new field and adding an extra query in `execute` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against selecting too broad in `start()` and then narrowing the results further in `execute()`. This will only maximize the risk of hitting some platform limits and affect the performance and execution time.

But it is advisable to limit the numer of fields, which you are selecting at `start()` and querying them at the `execute()` method. We are using this pattern widely and it solved a lot of query timeouts at the `start()` methods of our batches. Short example:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        [SELECT Id
         FROM Contact
         WHERE LeadSource = 'Web'
         AND Account.Type = 'Prospect'
        ]);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Contact> rawContacts){
    List<Contact> contacts = [
        SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Account.Name, Account.Type,
            (SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Cases)
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Id IN :rawContacts
    ];

    // further processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Right!
Alexander has given a prompt answer upon which i will add some more points.

There are cases where you need to have this in Start(),
For example. If the Query hits

> Too Many Query Rows : 50001 error

,
Then you might need to move the query to start as the Limit is not applicable there.